# What characters or character combinations are invalid when ValidateRequest is set to true?

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, xss, sql-injection

I've tried looking at the Microsoft site and Googling this but nobody seems to have an answer aside from the < and the >.  There's more to it than that though. I've noticed that the HTML entity starter of &# is invalid.  Is there anything else?  Does anyone have a complete list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[List of characters by framework version](http://www.jardinesoftware.net/2009/08/27/validaterequest-property-xss/)

> 1.1 Framework Validation:
>
> ```
> * &#
> * <alpha, <!, </
> * script
> * On handlers like onmouseenter, etc…
> * expression(
> * Looks for these starting characters (‘<’, ‘&’, ‘o’, ‘O’, ‘s’, ‘S’, ‘e’, ‘E’)
> ```
>
> This is obviously a pretty strict list
>   of items that would trigger a
>   validation error.   In the 2.0
>   Framework, Microsoft decided to loosen
>   the restrictions on this quite a bit. 
>   Below is the list of validation checks
>   in the 2.0 Framework.
>
> 2.0 Framework Validation:
>
> ```
> * &#
> * <alpha, <!, </, <?
> * Looks for these starting characters (‘<’, ‘&’)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a complete list, but why do you need it?
You can set ValidateRequest=false and [prevent for Script Injection for yourself.](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/chiwai/archive/2005/07/29/8720.aspx)

Maybe you will find the list here: [Allowing percents, angle-brackets, and other naughty things in the ASP.NET/IIS Request URL](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)

Comment: I need to know so QA can stop telling me they found a "bug" when they enter data that gets flagged by ValidateRequest.  I can't turn it off as our IT Security team demands that it be always on.  Not my call.