# Dangerous Request values with  ISO Latin-1 codes?

Tags: asp.net, html, character-encoding

I have an Asp.net form ( runat=Server)

Im trying to figure out what is the difference between HTML Entities and ISO Latin-1 codes   - and why does one Do cause exception while the other Isnt.

I have  input and button

```
     <input type="text"   value="<d"/>
     <asp:Button ID="s" runat="server" Text="press" />
```

[image]

when I press submit - it goes with Exception which is fine.
[image]

1 way to solve it is by encodeUriComponent :

so putting the value :

```
 value="%3Cd"/>
```

is fine and No expcetion on submit.

Also  , as we know - if i put 
`&gt;` or `&lt;` ( which is html entity) it wont go exception. (  it has other role in Html world - to DISPLAY '<' '>'  - and not try to parse them as html...)

[image]

(no exception - except the second press - because when its back from the server - the textbox shows `<d` which is bad...

NOw lets go to the  `ISO Latin-1 code` [like here](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

[image]

now lets try to put instead of  `<d` ----> `&#60;d`

[image]

and it goes **bang** !

[image]

1)why do i get an exception in the Latin code and not in the html entity ?

1)  what is the difference between them ?

2) when should i use one or another ?

### Edit

I know I can disable the checking by set validateRequest = false.
but my questions are not related to this.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: @AnthonyFaull Are you serious ? I know this command . butr my question  is so detailed , and your link wont give much help...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Latin example contains &#. Those are exactly the characters which trigger a validation error [What characters or character combinations are invalid when ValidateRequest is set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118876/what-characters-or-character-combinations-are-invalid-when-validaterequest-is-se). So no surprise here.