# MVC4 Posting HTML and validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

so it is possible that form just shows validation error (like HTML is not allowed) instead of throwing an exception

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

when I include HTML in input. I dont want to accept HTML, but I also dont like to get exception.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP .NET 4.0, request validation is enabled for all requests by default.

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

You can still force your app to ignore this check.

See link for details:-

[ValidateRequest="false" doesn't work in Asp.Net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4)

However, I wouldn't advocate this strategy.  It's much better to try to **validate the text with Javascript *before* sending to the server** to ensure it doesn't contain any characters that trip the ValidateRequest behaviour.

This question covers all of those characters:-

[What characters or character combinations are invalid when ValidateRequest is set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118876/what-characters-or-character-combinations-are-invalid-when-validaterequest-is-se)

If your user does not have Javascript enabled, you'll still hit the error.  In that (rare) case, you can fall back on `customErrors` so that you at least show something that is prettier than the yellow error page.

Comment: I would suggest that rather than modifying user entered data, it's much better to just encode it whenever it's displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle application behavior on errors in your web.config file:

```
</system.web>
…
   <customErrors defaultRedirect="/ErrorPage" mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>
…
</system.web>
```

Moreover, beside specifying whether to show detailed errors or not you can also redirect user to a specific page to show him custom errors pages which you have designed.

For more information about this check [msdn explanation for customErrors element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)